# First run with PDO getting a Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object error

Tags: php, pdo

This is my first run with PDO, not sure how much better it is than using mysqli but its part of a project I have to create.

Here is the code that is causing the message, all I am trying to do is update pieces of data within my db table.

```
    <?php
//PHP Data Objects
try{
    //Connect


    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname = company; charset=utf-8','root', 'bachi619');

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();

}


$id = 4;
$name = "logan";
$department = "Design";

$sth = $dbh->query("UPDATE employees SET department=:department,last_name=:lastname WHERE id=:id");

//bind
$sth->bindParam(':id',$id);
$sth->bindParam(':lastname',$name);
$sth->bindParam(':department',$department);

$sth->execute();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dsn should be non spaced

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=company','root', 'bachi619');
```

You need to prepare the SQL statement like this

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare( 'UPDATE employees SET department=:department,last_name=:lastname WHERE id=:id' );
```

Then bind the parameters

```
$sth->bindParam(':id',$id);
$sth->bindParam(':lastname',$name);
$sth->bindParam(':department',$department);
```

and finally execute the query

```
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: ok I have it like this, I did make the changes and the error message goes away but nothing updates still. Double checked the db and all the names seem to add up with the php code. Not sure why its not updating in the db

Comment: Also ensure that connection is successfully established

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
$dbh -> prepare("UPDATE employees SET department=:department,last_name=:lastname WHERE id=:id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prepare for PDO, check this https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE employees SET department=:department,last_name=:lastname WHERE id=:id' );
```